# Apply same function to multiple ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway I can simplify this JS:

```
$('#collapse_notebook').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('#notebook-caret').removeClass( "fa-caret-up" );
  $('#notebook-caret').addClass( "fa-caret-down" );
})

$('#collapse_note').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('#note-caret').removeClass( "fa-caret-up" );
  $('#note-caret').addClass( "fa-caret-down" );
})
```

Comment: You can use chaining like mentioned below. Depending on your markup, it could be possible to simplify it further also. Like for example if the element whose class is removed/added is a child of the selector on which the operation is done etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple selector Chaining is the word: `:)`

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- [Multiple selector chaining in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736811/multiple-selector-chaining-in-jquery)

How this is done:  *demo* http://jsfiddle.net/49NBu/ *(shows the extracting bit)*

- Extract the `id` and use `split` as in your case there is a common pattern of anything after `_` is what needed for the operation within the function.
- API : `split` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

**Code**

```
$('#collapse_note,#collapse_notebook').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  var id = $(this).prop('id').split('_')[1];

  $('#'+id+'-caret').removeClass( "fa-caret-up" );
  $('#'+id+'-caret').addClass( "fa-caret-down" );
})
```

Comment: This is not the same as the original ... the ```$('#note-caret')``` needs to change

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
('#collapse_notebook,#collapse_note').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  var curr_id = this.id.split('_')[1]
  $('#'+curr_id+'-caret').toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use comma separated multiple selectors:

```
$('#collapse_notebook,#collapse_note').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
 $("#"+this.id.replace('collapse_','')+"-caret").removeClass( "fa-caret-up" );
 $("#"+this.id.replace('collapse_','')+"-caret").addClass( "fa-caret-down" );
});
```