# javascript not showing elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a modal which should show position variable mention in my code 
here is my ejs code (i'm using ejs and node js and java script for modal)

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <%for(i=0;i<Vac.length;i++){%>
 <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">

     <h4 class="alert-heading">Postion:- <%=Vac[i].position%></h4>

  <hr>
  <h5>Type:- <%=Vac[i].type%></h5>

  <h6>Skills:- <%=Vac[i].Skills%></h6>
  <p class="lead"><%=Vac[i].Description%> </p>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onclick="showApply()">Apply</button>  


     <br> 
  </div>
  <%}%>
</div>
```

here is my javascript code for the modal

```
<script>
     function showApply()
     {
     $('#applyModal').modal('show');
      $('#applyModal').('#applyModaltitle').text($('#alert-heading'));
     } 
    </script>
```

but i'm getting the error as below:

```
SyntaxError: missing name after . operator[Learn More] careers:216:23 [Show/hide message details.] ReferenceError: showApply is not defined
```

can anybody tell me whats wrong and how i can correct it ?

Comment: `$('#applyModal').('#applyModaltitle')` That's not valid syntax, what were you trying to do there?

Comment: Appending to CertainPerformance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736811/multiple-selector-chaining-in-jquery

Comment: @CertainPerformance i'm trying to get the position variable from Vac array in the modal

Answer (score 0):

Refer to: [Multiple selector chaining in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736811/multiple-selector-chaining-in-jquery)

```
 function showApply()
 {
  $('#applyModal').modal('show');
  $('#applyModal').('#applyModaltitle').text($('#alert-heading'));
 }
```

The error you get tells you that showApply doesn't exist.
That is so, because there is a . (dot) operator that is wrong in this function.

You can try that:

```
 function showApply()
 {
  $('#applyModal').find('#applyModaltitle').innerHTML=$('#alert-heading').text;
  $('#applyModal').modal('show');
 }
```

Comment: i refereed but not understanding how i can solve it could help me out  a bit ?

Answer (score 0):

After Searching for the answer for many answer i had found this out from one of the answer on stackoverflow .Since I'm accessing data from database generated , i have to access data through the elements from the data set displayed like from my example :-

i have displayed my data in an alert box and from alert box i have to take the required data and displayed it in the modal,in order to display the data on the modal we have to do the following :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#modalname').on('show.bs.modal',function(e){
  var _button =$(e.relatedTarget);
  var info =_button.parents(".alert");
  var position=info.find(".classofelementneeded").text(); //text as i was using h5 tag for displaying data
  $(this).find("#element where you want to display data").val(position); //val because  i want to display data in text box
});
});
```

you can use this for displaying data from web page to modal via javascript