# How to combine jquery selector with 'this'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to combine these two statements into one.

```
$("#thing1, #thing2").toggleClass('myClass');
$(this).toggleClass('myClass');
```

Instincts told me this might work:

```
$("#thing1, #thing2", this).toggleClass('myClass');
```

but after some research, I discovered it is equivalent to this:

```
$(this).find("#thing1, #thing2").toggleClass('myClass');
```

I can't find anything in the documentation about doing this.

Comment: Migrate to framework (Vue, React, Svelte) :D

Comment: what is this referencing? can you provide [mcve]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple selector chaining in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736811/multiple-selector-chaining-in-jquery)

Comment: @GarvSahu That does not appear to work with the 'this' keyword

Comment: `$("#thing1, #thing2", $(this)).toggleClass('myClass');`

Comment: @AdityaParab That's effectively the same as what OP's instincts told them, but did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$("#thing1, #thing2").add(this).toggleClass('myClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`$.merge`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/)

```js
$('span').on('click', function() {
  $.merge($(this), $("#thing1, #thing2")).toggleClass('red')
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thing1">thing1</div>
<div id="thing2">thing2</div>
<span>click</span>
```